# basic graph data structure

Tags: c#, database, data-structures, unity-game-engine

I am trying to write a simple text-based game in Unity where the player must navigate from their bed 'let's say, 'A'' to an exit, 'G' by moving across 'nodes' that are directly attached. Here's an example of the information that I am trying to elegantly capture:

A is directly connected to B, C, and D
B is directly connected to A and C
C is directly connected to A and B
D is directly connected to A and E
E is directly connected to F and G
F is directly connected to nothing (let's say, game over?)
G is directly connected to E

so I need to be able to do the following:
1) store a bank of nodes
2) store connections between nodes that **may be one-way**
3) track the current position
4) (icing on the cake) **alter** these connections as things happen in-game

Any implementation I can create off the top of my head would not scale well to, let's say, 1000 nodes. How should I tackle this problem?

Comment: navmesh is your friend.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: BTW, 1000s of nodes is not very large. I wouldn't worry about the efficiency until you have to. Remember, "If it doesn't work, it doesn't matter how fast it doesn't work" - Ravera.

Answer (score 1):

**There a variety of graph data structures** you may take a look at. I suggest you to have a look at informative discussions about *efficient graph data structure* in this thread:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148313/what-is-the-most-space-efficient-way-to-implement-a-graph-data-structure

One of the efficient graph data structures it may fit your gaming purpose would be **using adjacency matrix** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix because you may find moving your character or object between two cells would happen quite often for gaming. Therefore, adjacency matrix helps you find the sibling cells of a particular cell quite fast. However, this approach requires some memory to store all possible adjacencies between any two sibling cells in your graph.

However, if your graph is definitely a directed graph where all connections between any two nodes are one-way. You may want to look at **adjacency list** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list  where you store the list of adjacency nodes in every cell. So it takes less time to look up the sibling of a particular cell.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is very similar to a road network:

```
class Crossroad {
   List<Road> roadList = new List<Road>();
}

class Road {
   Crossroad start;
   Crossroad end;
   bool isOneWay;
}

class RoadNetwork {
   List<Crossroad> crossroadList = new List<Crossroad>();
   List<Road> roadList = new List<Road>();
   Crossroad currentCrossroad;
}
```

1) store a bank of nodes: RoadNetwork.crossroadList

2) store connections between nodes that may be one-way: class Road

3) track the current position: RoadNetwork.currentCrossroad

4) (icing on the cake) alter these connections as things happen in-game: you can always change the crossroadList and roadList.